# ReactiveUI MVVM update property from event handler

Tags: c#, mvvm, domain-driven-design, reactiveui, avalonia

Im building a small MVVM application using the DDD principles.
In my ViewModel I have to update some properties whenever an event is fired.
Although my ViewModel updates the properties, these changes are not reflected in the UI.

Here is my (simplified) ViewModel:

```
public class DashboardViewModel : ReactiveObject, IAsyncHandle<RaceCreatedEvent>
{
    private readonly IQueryHandler<Query.Races.RaceQuery, Query.Races.Race?> raceQueryHandler;

    public DashboardViewModel(IQueryHandler<Query.Races.RaceQuery, Query.Races.Race?> raceQueryHandler)
    {
        this.raceQueryHandler = raceQueryHandler;

        // Here the method updates the properties & UI is updated
        SetRaceProperties();
    }

    [Reactive]
    public string NumberOfRaces { get; set; }

    [Reactive]
    public string NumberOfFinishedRaces { get; set; }

    [Reactive]
    public string NumberOfPendingRaces { get; set; }

    // Whenever a 'RaceCreatedEvent' has fired, this method is executed
    public async Task HandleAsync(RaceCreatedEvent domainEvent)
    {
        // Here the method updates the properties, but the UI is NOT updated
        await SetRaceProperties();
    }

    private async Task SetRaceProperties()
    {
        var data = await raceQueryHandler.HandleMultipleAsync(null);

        this.NumberOfRaces = $"{data.Count()} aangemaakte races";
        this.NumberOfPendingRaces = $"{data.Where(r => r != null && !r.Finished && !r.Started).Count()} races in afwachting";
        this.NumberOfFinishedRaces = $"{data.Where(r => r != null && r.Finished).Count()} afgelopen races";
    }
}
```

When `SetRaceProperties` is called from the constructor, the properties & UI are updated.
Whenever the method `SetRaceProperties` is fired from my event handler, the properties are updated, but not the UI.

Here's my view binding:

```
<TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Classes="Body1" Text="{Binding NumberOfRaces}" />
<TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Classes="Body1" Text="{Binding NumberOfPendingRaces}" />
<TextBlock Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Classes="Body1" Text="{Binding NumberOfFinishedRaces}" />
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With RxUI you can do a `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler.Schedule(() =>{ ... set your properties ...});` -- I suspect you've got event handler firing on a non-UI thread.

Comment: Somewhere I forget where I saw that a [Reactive] Fody property should not have the assignment at the end. Maybe someone can add if that's not the case or  why not if so.   You don't have your view binding above. Do you want to include that code?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Using the RxApp scheduler did not work. @kenny I have updated my initial question with the view binding.

Comment: @K.L. looks perfect.  Maybe I wasn't clear and I can't remember where I saw it but can you remove the Property assignment after the get;setter > = "Laden...";

Comment: Oh I read over it. I've tried it, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. For me, the solution was not to call the Task method async. Have you tried this because you call await first and then call this. Maybe that leads to a problem. At the first time you call the SetRaceProperties method you dont use await.

Comment: Yes, I have tried not awaiting the method, but it doesn't help.